# How to make a round rect button with two rounded corners and two rectangular edges

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

What I want is for the buttons to look like this:

[image]

I just added my buttons from interface builder and connected them to the code. Does anyone know how to do this? And is it possible to do this with a UITextField object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the standard `UIButton` is not sufficient, then create your own View:

You create an `UIView` class and in `drawRect` method you
draw a path consisting of 4 arc with 90° (corners) and connect that with `CGPathLineTo`.
Use corner radius, width and height as paramter.

Further tipps: 
use `CGTransformMakeScale` such that you rectangle  is transformed to a squre with side length 1.
 This simplifies the calculation of the arc parameter.

Dont forget to tranform the corner radius, too (e.g with scale.x)

Comment: I tried looking up the CGPathLineTo in the Xcode documentation, and I couldn't find it.

Comment: @ChandlerDeAngelis try harder: what about CGPathAddLineTooPoint

Comment: I found it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a `UITableViewController` with the sections set to be `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. Unless if you can find a background for each button, this is what the settings app uses.

**To make a UITableView:**

- Each of the `groups` is a `section`, so you'll want to return how many sections you have with `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`.
- For every *section*, you want to say how many rows there are with `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.
- You'll want to customize each cell with `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` (which, by the way, tells you which section's particular row you're modifying in the indexPath variable).
- You'll want to handle the row click in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. The the code below helps you deselect the table view. :`[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`
- also use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` to handle what happens after tapping a specific row.

Tutorial that really explains this stuff in detail: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Apple Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

For the `UITextField`, you can set this to *Grouped* in the Interface Builder or pragrammagitaly to this: `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect`

Good Luck!